# Symbolizing line thickness by M-values

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, m-values

Is there a possibility in QGIS 3 to render line thickness by M values on every vertex?

The new `Interpolated Line` symbol layer type introduced in version 3.20 seems suitable for the task, but so far looks like it supports just interpolationt between line start and end points. There is no option to use M-values.

Example line below. I would like to interpolate between the line vertices of width e.g. 10 - 20 m thick.

[image: line with 8 vertices and different m values]

Comment: So, the line should become gradually thicker/thinner between two vertices with different values?

Comment: you would need to cut you lines every 10-20 m and sample the M-value for these segments.

Comment: @Erik Yes, that's the idea. Actually a workaround could be to use `Points along geometry` and symbolise points with line szmbol and M value controlled stroke width. But there is no nice join style on the edges.

Comment: Is `buffer_by_m` expression answer your question : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#buffer-by-m ? or maybe create a new line layer with single lines instead of polylines.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Yes, this could definetely be it. There's even a tool `Variable wifth buffer (by M value)` based on this function. If there's no way of using line symbology you could put that as an aswer.

Comment: You can for your line layer add a symbol layer with a `geometry generator` function, `polygone` type and as expression, use `buffer_by_m($geometry)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this :

1. Go in the <kbd>Layer Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Symbology</kbd> tab
2. Add a symbol layer (or use the default one) and select as `Symbol layer type` : <kbd>Geometry Generator</kbd> and as `Geometry type` <kbd>Polygon / MultiPolygon</kbd>
3. As expression for the geometry generator, enter : `buffer_by_m($geometry)`

The result is very similar to `Interpolated Line`, work as you wanted and attached to the polyline layer, so the geometry is polyline, only the render is a polygon.

Below a screenshot of a comparison between `Interpolated Line` (light green) and `buffer_by_m` (hashed blue) :

[image: comparison between interpolated line and buffer_by_m]